# How do I replace all >x values in column using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm trying to replace all the higher values than my limit in Pandas column like this:

```
df_train['IsAlone'].replace([>0],1)
```

but this obviously is not working

I got my code working like this:

```
for i in range(len(df_train)):
    if df_train.iat[i,8] > 0:
        df_train.iat[i,8] = 1
```

but I'm wondering if there is a more universal way to replace values as the .iat solution is prone to bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply it like so:

```
df_train.loc[df_train['IsAlone'] > 0, 'IsAlone'] = 1
```

Answer (score -2):

df[df.IsAlone>0]=1 ?  Wasn’t able to check on iPhone if worked or not

Comment: This replaces all values in all columns with 1, not just the column `"IsAlone"`.